# Camel 2.13.1 MyBatis 3.2.7 Batch Insert to Oracle 11g Table ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle11g, apache-camel, mybatis

I'm trying to insert a list of data to a table using MyBatis InsertList Batch from a Camel Route. The **Batch fails with exception  java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended** ( more details below).

I was able to insert the list of data without issues from MyBatis API (see section 6 in the post),  **but it fails only when used from a camel route.**

The query is  fine (refer 5. SQL Query on client in the post) as I was able to insert the data successfully from a a SQL client. I tried several options and researched a lot but not sure what the issue is yet.

I appreciate if you could shed some light on the issue.

**Technology Used:** 
Java version "1.7.0_55"
Apache Camel 2.13.1
MyBatis 3.2.7
Oracle 11g

I posted the same question to [Camel Users](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-2-13-1-MyBatis-Batch-Insert-to-Oracle-11g-Table-ORA-00933-SQL-command-not-properly-ended-tt5754248.html)

Below are the details related to the issue:

**1. Camel Route:**

from("timer:foo?period=10000") 
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.GET))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, constant(RestURLs.TRANSACTION_BIDS_UNQUALIFIED_URL))
    .process(new CamelGETMessageProcessor())
    .to("restlet:http://someaddress.com/app/cts/bids")
    .unmarshal(jaxbDataFormat)
    .process(new TransactionBidsProcessor())                            **.to("mybatis:insertTransactionBidDetail?statementType=InsertList&executorType=batch")** 
    .end();

**2. Mapper Query:**

```
<insert id="insertTransactionBidDetail" parameterType="com.isone.cts.rest.binding.cts.TransactionBidsResponse">
        INSERT ALL
        <foreach item="p" collection="transactionBids.transactionBid"
            open="" close="" separator=")">
            into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T 
            (message_request_id, transaction_source,
            transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref,
            gis_identifier, jess_etag_id)
            values(#{messageRequestID,jdbcType=NUMERIC},
            #{p.transactionSource,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
            #{p.transactionSink,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
            #{p.transactionUserRef,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
            #{p.gisIdentifier,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
            #{p.jessETagID,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
        </foreach>
        )SELECT * FROM dual     
    </insert>
```

**3. SQL Log**

[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] DEBUG transactionBidsMapper.insertTransactionBidDetail  - ==>  Preparing: INSERT ALL into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) into TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T (message_request_id, transaction_source, transaction_sink, transaction_user_ref, gis_identifier, jess_etag_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )SELECT * FROM dual

[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] DEBUG transactionBidsMapper.insertTransactionBidDetail  - ==> Parameters: 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE0(String), NODENYISO0(String), USERREFGPKL44220(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1110RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE1(String), NODENYISO1(String), USERREFGPKL44221(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1111RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE2(String), NODENYISO2(String), USERREFGPKL44222(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1112RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE3(String), NODENYISO3(String), USERREFGPKL44223(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1113RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE4(String), NODENYISO4(String), USERREFGPKL44224(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1114RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE5(String), NODENYISO5(String), USERREFGPKL44225(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1115RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE6(String), NODENYISO6(String), USERREFGPKL44226(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1116RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE7(String), NODENYISO7(String), USERREFGPKL44227(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1117RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE8(String), NODENYISO8(String), USERREFGPKL44228(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1118RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE9(String), NODENYISO9(String), USERREFGPKL44229(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _1119RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE10(String), NODENYISO10(String), USERREFGPKL442210(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _11110RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE11(String), NODENYISO11(String), USERREFGPKL442211(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _11111RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE12(String), NODENYISO12(String), USERREFGPKL442212(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _11112RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE13(String), NODENYISO13(String), USERREFGPKL442213(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _11113RCA(String), 1406290673069(BigDecimal), NODEISONE14(String), NODENYISO14(String), USERREFGPKL442214(String), HASHMASHSMASH(String), SCA_PSE _11114RCA(String)
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] DEBUG org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction  - Rolling back JDBC Connection

**4. Below is the exception thrown.**

[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-sporeddy-51161-1406290670797-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-sporeddy-51161-1406290670797-0-2). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: transactionBidsMapper.insertTransactionBidDetail (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

#### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: transactionBidsMapper.insertTransactionBidDetail (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] INFO  org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.Tracer  - ID-sporeddy-51161-1406290670797-0-2 >>> (route5) mybatis://insertTransactionBidDetail?executorType=batch&statementType=InsertList --> OnException[PersistenceException] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{CamelMyBatisResult=-2147482646, breadcrumbId=ID-sporeddy-51161-1406290670797-0-1, firedTime=Fri Jul 25 08:17:53 EDT 2014, CamelMyBatisStatementName=insertTransactionBidDetail}, BodyType:com.isone.cts.rest.binding.cts.TransactionBidsResponse, Body:com.isone.cts.rest.binding.cts.TransactionBidsResponse@137c799
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] INFO  org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.Tracer  - ID-sporeddy-51161-1406290670797-0-2 >>> OnException[PersistenceException] --> com.isone.cts.camel.processor.CamelPersistenceProcessor@19af694 <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{CamelMyBatisResult=-2147482646, breadcrumbId=ID-sporeddy-51161-1406290670797-0-1, firedTime=Fri Jul 25 08:17:53 EDT 2014, CamelMyBatisStatementName=insertTransactionBidDetail}, BodyType:com.isone.cts.rest.binding.cts.TransactionBidsResponse, Body:com.isone.cts.rest.binding.cts.TransactionBidsResponse@137c799
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] DEBUG com.isone.cts.camel.processor.CamelPersistenceProcessor  -  Message in CamelPersistenceProcessor com.isone.cts.rest.binding.cts.TransactionBidsResponse@137c799
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] DEBUG com.isone.cts.camel.processor.CamelPersistenceProcessor  -  Headers in CamelPersistenceProcessor {CamelMyBatisResult=-2147482646, breadcrumbId=ID-sporeddy-51161-1406290670797-0-1, firedTime=Fri Jul 25 08:17:53 EDT 2014, CamelMyBatisStatementName=insertTransactionBidDetail}
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] DEBUG com.isone.cts.camel.processor.CamelPersistenceProcessor  - Exception caught org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: transactionBidsMapper.insertTransactionBidDetail (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

#### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: transactionBidsMapper.insertTransactionBidDetail (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://foo] DEBUG com.isone.cts.camel.processor.CamelPersistenceProcessor  -  PersistenceException getResponseBody

#### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: transactionBidsMapper.insertTransactionBidDetail (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

#### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: transactionBidsMapper.insertTransactionBidDetail (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

**5. SQL Query on client**

INSERT ALL
INTO TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T
  (
    message_request_id,
    transaction_source,
    transaction_sink,
    transaction_user_ref,
    gis_identifier,
    jess_etag_id
  )
  VALUES
  (
    1406037318681,
    'NODEISONE14',
    'NODENYISO0',
    'USERREFGPKL44220',
    'HASHMASHSMASH',
    'SCA_PSE _1110RCA'
  )
INTO TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T
  (
    message_request_id,
    transaction_source,
    transaction_sink,
    transaction_user_ref,
    gis_identifier,
    jess_etag_id
  )
  VALUES
  (
    1406037318681,
    'NODEISONE14',
    'NODENYISO0',
    'USERREFGPKL44220',
    'HASHMASHSMASH',
    'SCA_PSE _1110RCA'
  )
INTO TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T
  (
    message_request_id,
    transaction_source,
    transaction_sink,
    transaction_user_ref,
    gis_identifier,
    jess_etag_id
  )
  VALUES
  (
    1406037318681,
    'NODEISONE14',
    'NODENYISO0',
    'USERREFGPKL44220',
    'HASHMASHSMASH',
    'SCA_PSE _1110RCA'
  )
INTO TRANSACTION_BIDS_DATA_T
  (
    message_request_id,
    transaction_source,
    transaction_sink,
    transaction_user_ref,
    gis_identifier,
    jess_etag_id
  )
  VALUES
  (
    1406037318681,
    'NODEISONE14',
    'NODENYISO0',
    'USERREFGPKL44220',
    'HASHMASHSMASH',
    'SCA_PSE _1110RCA'
  )
SELECT * FROM dual

**6. Works fine when the same query is run from MyBatis API**

```
  private static void insertTransactionBidsDetailComplex() {
            SqlSession session = null;
            try {
                TransactionBidsResponse transactionBidsResponse = new TransactionBidsResponse();
                TransactionBids transactionBids = new TransactionBids();
                transactionBids.getTransactionBid().addAll(
                        TransactionBidsDataGenerator.buildTransactionBidList());
                transactionBidsResponse.setTransactionBids(transactionBids);
                transactionBidsResponse.setMessageRequestID(new BigInteger(String
                        .valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));
                transactionBidsResponse.setHeader(buildHeader());
                session = getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
                insert = session.insert(
                        "transactionBidsMapper.insertTransactionBidDetail",
                        transactionBidsResponse);
                session.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                session.rollback();
            } finally {
                // close session
                session.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   The issue lies with the setting below in MyBatis Configuration file:
<setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="false" />
```

On painfully debugging end to end, I noticed that an exception is thrown at Line No: 103 batchResult.setUpdateCounts(stmt.executeBatch()); in BatchExecutor.java (myBatis 3.2.7 jar). Since the option to use useGeneratedKeys is set to true in MyBatis Configuration, what happens at this point is:  **RETURNING ROWID INTO ?** is added to the end of the query  and this was throwing an exception.

I changed the to false and it worked.

As a note, do not set useGeneratedKeys  to true unless you are sure that every query needs the returned ROWID.  You can set the  useGeneratedKeys option in the mapper files for more control e.g. below:

```
<insert id="insertSomething" useGeneratedKeys="true"
    keyProperty="id">
<!-- Some Query  -->
</insert>
```